# place url variable after ’where’ statement in sql query

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, coldfusion

I have a in house cold fusion script. i want to put the url.variable into the sql select statement as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id
WHERE #a.url.variable# LIKE'%test%'
```

I cant seem to get it to display any data when I put the variable right after the word 'WHERE'

Comment: I have the wildcard in the real code. I just forgot to add it to the example above. It does not work with the wildcards.

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? What is the value of `#a.url.variable#` and the sql generated? (Also, I hope you are validating and scrubbing the variable because using it directly in sql is dangerous, as Barry pointed out)

Comment: may be not related to question but do not take url variable as table name otherwise your making SQL injection easy for this.. Too Bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put hashes around it as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 a 
JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id 
WHERE a.#url.variable# LIKE '%test%'
```

You can't use a cfqueryparam in this case so I'd also ensure that URL.variable has been escaped of any SQL injection characters before using it in your query.

Comment: Sorry. I have hashes in the original code. It doesnt seem to work either. Should it be working correctly?

Comment: Yes, that will work perfectly. Are you getting an error, is so, what are you getting? Does the field a.#url.VARIABLE# exist in a?

Comment: Your hashes in your question are different from Barry's hashes.

Comment: Yes, you have #a.url.variable#, it should be a.#url.variable#

Answer (score 0):

If it's a string in a cfscipt block you will need:

```
"SELECT... " & url.variable & " LIKE..."
```

Or if not, make sure it's contained in a

```
<cfoutput>
    SELECT... #url.variable# LIKE...
</cfoutput>
```